# Rewrite gets completely ignored

Tags: wp-query, rewrite-rules

I have created a small function to rewrite a get variable. First, I created the page 'download', and I want a get variable to be used for the file attribute. This is an working URL:
http://example.com/download/?file=file

But when I use add_rewrite_rule to make the url look like this:
http://example.com/download/file,
It doesn't work.

The function:

```
function createRewriteRules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('download/([^/]*)', 'index.php/download/?file=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'createRewriteRules');
```

I have also tried the following:

```
function createRewriteRules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('download/([^/]*)', 'download/?file=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'createRewriteRules');
```

On both, $wp_query returns "file" as pagename instead of "download".

Updated:

```
function createRewriteRules() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%file%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('download/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php/?pagename=download&file=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```

And a reflush doesn't work eighter, while index.php/?pagename=download&file=file does work. The rewrite rule also got added to the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rerite rule is incorrect. It should be (assuming `download` is name or slug of the page):

```
add_rewrite_rule('^download/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=download&file=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

Also, you need to declare the `file` query var. A sample and working code:

```
function createRewriteRules() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%file%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^download/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=download&file=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'createRewriteRules');
```

Note: Don't forget to flush rewrite rules after adding new rewrite rules.

Comment: Doesn't work... I've added the results to my original question.

Comment: Strange, I tested de code before posting and tested again and it is working. That extra / after index.php is really irrelevant in most servers and makes no difference. It is also not correct from a strict syntax perspective. I'm really curious and I would like to know how it can be working with it while not working without it. To be homest, I think you have not tested properly this code.

Comment: I found that the problem didn't had anything to do with the add_rewrite_rule tag. There was another .htaccess file in the root folder of the server (where I didn't had access to) which caused some problems. I'll mark your answer as the correct one as normally, that would have fixed it.